# .NET Core Replacement for ConvertTimeToUtc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

What happened to ConvertTimeToUtc in .NET Core? I know it's not there anymore, but has it been replaced by anything else? This is how I used to take a clients Date and Time input, and then convert it to UTC to store in database:

```
var timeZoneInfo=TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(viewModel.EventTimeZone);
var completeStartDate=TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(viewModel.StartDate,timeZoneInfo);
```

This has worked great, until .NET Core. Any current examples I can find all seem to be using 'ConvertTime', but they are going from UTC to local, which is the opposite of what I am going for here. So can anyone out there tell me how I can accomplish this same feat in .NET Core? I am currently using this framework setup in my project.json file:

```
  "frameworks": {
        "netcoreapp1.0": {
            "imports": [
                "dotnet5.6",
                "portable-net45+win8"
            ]
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime` and then choose `destinationTimeZone` (the third parameter) to be UTC:

```
var timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(viewModel.EventTimeZone);
var completeStartDate =
    TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(viewModel.StartDate,timeZoneInfo, TimeZoneInfo.Utc);
```